# How to get date in d/m/y format using javascript date.js library?

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to get next 30th date from a specified date using javascript library date.js. here is my code:

```js
<script src="date.js"> 
var val = (document.formi.pack_val.value) * (30) ;
var d = Date.today().add(val).days();
document.formi.date.value = d;
</script>
```

However I'm getting output like this:
Tue Apr 28 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

How to get output like this?

28/4/2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use .toString('dd/MM/yyyy') like this:

```
<script src="date.js"> 
    var val = (document.formi.pack_val.value) * (30) ;
    var d = Date.today().add(val).days();
    document.formi.date.value = d.toString('dd/MM/yyyy');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

As standard JS does not support a (dd/mm/yyyy) format I'd recommend downloading and installing Date.js: https://github.com/datejs/Datejs

After which you should be able to reference

```
new Date().toString('M/d/yyyy')
```

where you have

```
.toString('dd/MM/yyyy');
```